# vuejs Setting Dynamic path to template's src

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an vue application which I have divided in components kinda manner seen below.
[image]

What I want is to bind `src` property in `<template>` like below so that I could have a dynamic path every time a user asks for different template to get loaded.
[image]

The .ts file will have same code in use for every different template. which prompt me to ask this question.
Please suggest a solution to it. Or am I going into right direction or not to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve dynamic templates being rendered is using dynamic component rendering:

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="selectedComponent = 'app-quote'">Quote</button>
    <button @click="selectedComponent = 'app-author'">Author</button>
    <button @click="selectedComponent = 'app-new'">New</button>
    <hr>
    <component :is="selectedComponent"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<srcript>
  import Quote from './components/Quote.vue'
  import Author from './components/Author.vue'
  import New from './components/New.vue'

  data: function() {
    return {
      selectedComponent: 'app-quote'
    }
  },
  components: {
    'app-quote': Quote,
    'app-author': Author,
    'app-new': New
  }
</script>
```